# Installing css-loader via npm gives "error parsing json"

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-2015, css-loader

I'm trying to install css-loader (v 0.28.2) to a Visual Studio 2015 project via npm:

```
>npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

This gives the long error copied at the bottom. We are running this behind a corporate firewall and have already followed the instructions for registering the machine proxy [here](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/). That worked for all packages except for css-loader.

It appears from the error that it's actually being generated from a dependency package called "index-of". Has anyone seen this before? How do I fix this?

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x8
6)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "css-load
er"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
npm ERR! "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
npm ERR! <title>Notification: Proxy Authorization Required</title>
npm ERR! <style type="text/css">
npm ERR! body {
npm ERR!   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
npm ERR!   font-size: 14px;
npm ERR!   color:#333333;
npm ERR!   background-color: #ffffff;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! h1 {
npm ERR!   font-size: 18px;
npm ERR!   font-weight: bold;
npm ERR!   text-decoration: none;
npm ERR!   padding-top: 0px;
npm ERR!   color: #2970A6;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! a:link {
npm ERR!     color: #2970A6;
npm ERR!   text-decoration: none;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! a:hover {
npm ERR!     color: #2970A6;
npm ERR!   text-decoration: underline;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! p.buttonlink {
npm ERR!   margin-bottom: 24px;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .copyright {
npm ERR!   font-size: 12px;
npm ERR!   color: #666666;
npm ERR!   margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
npm ERR!
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .details {
npm ERR!   font-size: 14px;
npm ERR!   color: #969696;
npm ERR!   border: none;
npm ERR!   padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
npm ERR!   margin: 0px 10px 10px 35px;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! .shadow {
npm ERR!   border: 3px solid #9f9f9f;
npm ERR!   padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
npm ERR!   margin: 10px 35px 0px 30px;
npm ERR!   background-color: #ffffff;
npm ERR!   width: 600px;
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
npm ERR!   -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
npm ERR!   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
npm ERR!   /* For IE 8 */
npm ERR!   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Dir
ection=135, Color='cccccc')";
npm ERR!   /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
npm ERR!   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Directio
n=135, Color='cccccc');
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! .logo {
npm ERR!   border: none;
npm ERR!   margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! </style>
npm ERR! </head>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <body>
npm ERR! <div class="logo"></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
npm ERR! <div class="shadow">
npm ERR! <h1>This Page Cannot Be Displayed</h1>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <p>
npm ERR! Authentication is required to access the Internet using this system.
npm ERR! A valid user ID and password must be entered when prompted.
npm ERR! </p>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <p>
npm ERR! If you have questions, please contact
npm ERR! your organization's network administrator
npm ERR! and provide the codes shown below.
npm ERR! </p>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! </div>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! <div class="details"><p>
npm ERR! Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 20:43:19 GMT<br />
npm ERR! Username: <br />
npm ERR! Source IP: 10.90.8.164<br />
npm ERR! URL: GET http://registry.npmjs.org/indexes-of<br />
npm ERR! Category: Computers and Internet<br />
npm ERR! Reason: UNKNOWN<br />
npm ERR! Notification: PROXY_AUTH_REQUIRED
npm ERR! </p></div>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects_VS2015\Angular2Application4\Angular2Application4\npm-de
bug.log
```

Comment: are you gettting both errors `token >` and the `install errors` ? I dont think so

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The only errors I know of are what is dumped out in the cmd window. Unexpected token < is the first.

Comment: I can't understand your reply! Elaborate it

Comment: I'm trying. The only errors I know of are what I posted above. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: `json token <` will be at run time and it must be in the browser console. However `delete npm cache` and retry. if error still exists. update the package.json to post

Comment: I assume you meant "npm cache clean". I did that, but the package still won't install. I get the same error(s) from above.